# Erlang : How to force domain name on a cluster node?

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing

I would like to start a cluster node on a dedicated server.

However When I start it with this command line :

```
erl -pa ebin -name myserver -setcookie abc
```

It starts with a certain domain name:

```
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
(myserver@sd-XXXXX.dedibox.fr)1>
```

I would like it to start on another domain name like : myserver@mydomain.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify the domain as part of -name

```
> erl -pa ebin -name myserver@mydomain.com -setcookie abc
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]
...
(myserver@mydomain.com)1> node().
'myserver@mydomain.com'
```